# python beginner performance : for loop Vs iterator Vs Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, performance, for-loop, iterator

for learning purpose, i got a bank statement
as csv file :

```
data = pd.read_csv('./datasets/code/analyse/operations.csv')
data.columns = ['identifiant_transaction', 'date_operation', 'date_valeur', 'libelle', 'debit', 'credit', 'solde']
print(data.libelle.head())
```

witch display like this :

```
0    FORFAIT COMPTE SUPERBANK XX XX XX XX
1                 CARTE XX XX CHEZ LUC XX
2          PRELEVEMENT XX TELEPHONE XX XX
3                 CARTE XX XX XX XX XX XX
4                       CARTE XX XX XX XX
Name: libelle, dtype: object
```

my goal is to extract the most commun words use in the "libelle" :

```
XX          142800
CARTE        24700
VIREMENT      2900
ROBINSON      2000
ANCIENS       2000
```

i first try :

```
def most_common_words(labels):
    words = []
    for lab in labels:
        words += lab.split(" ")
    return Counter(words).most_common()
```

then :

```
def most_common_words_iter(labels):
    return Counter(chain(*(words.split(" ") for words in labels))).most_common()
```

and finally :

```
def most_common_words_pandas(labels):    
    return labels.str.split().explode().value_counts(sort=True)
```

my hypothesis was that the first solution will be slower because of the intermediate list, and that the second or the third solution would perhaps induce some free integrated optimizations (vectorization, better flow management, less memory allocation ...). but, no :-/

[python vs iterable vs pandas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tr1Yu.png)

Is it as it should be? Or should I do it differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some improvement (30-40%) by modyfing "python" version:

```
def most_common_words(labels):
    words = ' '.join(labels.values)
    words = words.split(' ')
    return Counter(words).most_common()
```

Comment: thank you, your solution is also easy to read. it puts the other two even further behind, which makes me think even more that I missed something about them

Comment: I find `pandas` very often not most efficient - it is good for writing code fast and clean. When such part becomes bottleneck I have to rewrite it to numpy/pure python

Comment: Thank you. that might be the accepted solution. I'll leave it open a bit more to see if anyone has any other insight